# How do I get the h1 inside a loop in simple html dom?

Tags: php, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

How do I get the h1 inside a loop in simple html dom?
This is the code that I'm using to fetch images and save them in a folder.
It works fine.

But I don't have any idea on how to save h1 as file name

```
include("simple_html_dom.php");
$files = file_get_contents("http://picjumbo.com/page/2/");
$html = new simple_html_dom();  
$html->load($files);  


//Get all the item-wrap divs
foreach($html->find('div[class=item_wrap]') as $item_wrap){
    //fetch each image and save it
    foreach($item_wrap->find('img[class=image]') as $img){  
        $img_src = explode('/',$img->src);
        $img_src  = explode('-',$img_src[5]);
        $img = $img_src[0];
        $url = 'http://picjumbo.com/wp-content/themes/picjumbofree/run.php?download&d='.$img.'.jpg';
        copy($url, 'images/'.$img.'.jpg');
    }
}
```

I tried this but it is not working.I can't get my head around it

```
foreach($html->find('div[class=item_wrap]') as $item_wrap){
    foreach($item_wrap->find('img[class=image]') as $img){  
        $img_src = explode('/',$img->src);
        $img_src  = explode('-',$img_src[5]);
        $img = $img_src[0];

        //this throws an error (I know a foreach is required but how do I save h1 as file name with it?)
        $h1 = $item_wrap->find('h1')->plaintext;

        $url = 'http://picjumbo.com/wp-content/themes/picjumbofree/run.php?download&d='.$h1.'.jpg';
        copy($url, 'images/'.$img.'.jpg');
    }
}
```

You get the idea right?I just want to save the image as h1.
Need your help!!!

Comment: Someone Please help!!

Comment: what do you use simplexml?

Comment: k try `$h1 = $item_wrap->find('h1',0)->plaintext` and let me know the resonpose.

Comment: What about `$h1 = $item_wrap->find('h1',0)->innertext` what do you get, An error ?

Comment: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: See demo here https://eval.in/99351

Comment: it works in your code but not on mine.Is there no other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Find('...', $index)` returns the Nth element specified by `$index` (zero based), and If `$index` is not set it returns an array...

So, since you know there's only one `h1` in each block, then it willl correspond to the first element in the array returnd by `find()`:

```
$h1 = $item_wrap->find('h1', 0)->plaintext;
```

You can also try:

```
$h1Temp = $item_wrap->find('h1');
$h1 = $h1Temp[0]->plaintext;
```

**Edit:** Damn, I see you already got similar answer in the comments, i'll leave it anyway here, it may help others..